# How to Load .sql file to Scala?

Tags: sql, scala, hive

I have a long SQL query stored in a data.sql file. I want to execute this file in my Scala code. 
With a sqlQuery string, I use a spark.sql(sqlQuery) to execute sql. But with a .sql file, how should I execute it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

You can try this flow (`Spark 1.6.2, Scala 2.10.5`)

**Create a file with the query**

```
$ cat query.sql
select * from mydb.mytable
```

If you have `HDFS`, you can upload file to `HDFS` (say at `/hdfs/path/query.sql`)
If you have it locally, then say it is at `/local/path/query.sql`

**Run in spark shell**

```
$ spark-shell
:
:
Created sql context (with Hive support)..
SQL context available as sqlContext.
```

(If loading from local)

```
scala> val myQueryFile = sc.textFile("file:///local/path/query.sql")
```

(If loading from `HDFS`)

```
scala> val myQueryFile = sc.textFile("/hdfs/path/query.sql")
```

Execute and view result

```
scala> val myQuery = myQueryFile.take(1)
scala> val myResultDf = sqlContext.sql(myQuery(0))
scala> myResultDf.show
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `scala.io.Source`:

```
import scala.io.Source

val sqlQuery = Source.fromFile("path/to/data.sql").mkString //read file
spark.sql(sqlQuery) //execute query
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider that you have the below **.sql** file which have the data like below and separated with semi column (`;`).

```
create table table1(id int, name string);
create table table2(id int, login_time timestamp, logout_time timestamp)
```

Using the below code, it will read the file and convert the contents into string. Then it will split the string with semi-column and then execute each sql sequentially.

```
sc.textFile("/data.sql").collect().mkString.split(";").foreach(qry => spark.sql(qry))
```

`sc` means `sparkContext`. This creates the connection to the cluster. You need not need to define this variable, you can use `sc.textFile` directly. Similarly `spark` is the spark session variable. You need not need to define this, you can directly use `spark.sql` to execute sqls.