# Execute .sql in scala loop and assign to DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm fighting with spark-shell in Scala.

I got a file .sql which contains:

```py
select count(*) from my_table union all
select count(*) from my_table_2;
```

Also have a 2nd file to invoke with spark-shell.
This file contains:

```py
import scala.io.Source
val sqlQuery - Source.fromFile("metadata/usr_home/2_pre_checks.sql").mkString.split(;).foreach(query => spark.sql(query).show(false))
```

I cant manage to somehow "get" query result (not scripts in .sql) or even better put query result to some dataframe. Any helps/ideas?

result on cluster is something like that:

```
+---------+
|count(*)|
+---------+
| 1         - first select
| 0         - second select
```

sqlQuery: Unit = ()

I found something similar in this topic:
[How to Load .sql file to Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240926/how-to-load-sql-file-to-scala?newreg=5a5be2dd59c44170930aa43273050ed0)

but
after using his command:

```py
sc.textFile("/data.sql").collect().mkString.split(";").foreach(qry => spark.sql(qry))
```

im getting error:

```py
not enough arguments for method collect: (pf: PartificalFunction[Char.B])Iterator[B].
```

Comment: In your first example, what does `spark.sql(query)` gives you as return type?

Comment: hmm, dunno how to check it. But after query is completed at end it shows : "sqlQuery: Unit = ()"

Comment: found something like that about foreach: "foreach(f : scala.Function1[T, scala.Unit]) : scala.Unit", it looks like it converting to Unit anyway?. Im not an expert but maybe foreach is necessary to use over there. I need to open file with multiple sql statements > mkString to one line > split';' > execute in loop > collect executed queries to DataFrame

Comment: My point was that `spark.sql(query)` already gives you a `Dataframe`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#sql(sqlText:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.